# Why explicit typecasting is required here?

Tags: c++, typecasting-operator

Why we explicitly need to typecast `int` to `long long` in multiplication?

`t=(long long)n*(long long)n` gives correct answer but 
`t=n*n` gives wrong answer:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int n=100000;
long long int t;
t=(long long)n*(long long)n;
//t=n*n  (This gives wrong answer)
printf("%lld",t);
return 0;
}
```

`t=(long long)n*(long long)n` gives `10000000000`
where as
`t=n*n` gives `1410065408`
Why is it so?

Comment: `n` is an `int`, so `n*n` is also an `int`, and `10000000000` won't fit into an `int` on most machines. If you change `int n = 100000;` to `long long n = 100000;` then that would also fix the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `n` is an `int` type, `n * n` is an `int` type too. There's no "dynamic widening" in C++.

Writing `1LL * n * n` forces implicit conversions of the `n`s to `long long` types.

Finally, note that even `100000` *can* be too big for an `int` - `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` can be as small as 32767. If you want your code to be *portable* you need to write `long n = 100000;` and the expression for `t` as given.